# Migrate away from settings file

Tags: c#, .net

I use a settings file in my project in addition to a configuration file, and I wish to move away from using the settings file in preference to the configuration file.

The settings file is the default `.net` application setting mechanism (`ApplicationSettingsBase`), and my configuration file is a custom class that I serialize and `deserialize` manually.

I have successfully in the past applied the `NeedUpgrade/Upgrade()` logic to keep settings from previous versions, but somehow it seems settings are lost non-the-less.

The difference with this project in regards to earlier projects, is that it is deployed using Click-Once.

To work around the problem, I wish to move away from the settings file all together and rather use my configuration file which is stored in a static folder (`Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`), but I do not know how I best would proceed in managing this migration/change.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you are re-inventing the wheel? The configuration mechanism from .NET is extremely flexible. You can save whatever data structures you need.

Comment: Like i wrote, somehow the settings are lost in the upgrade.